# Homology isomorphism between H-spaces

Tags: homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

In Neisendorfer's book "Algebraic Methods in Unstable Homotopy Theory", on page 118, it is mentioned that a homology isomorphism between $H$-spaces is a weak homotopy equivalence. How does one prove it?

Comment: basically there is no need for local coefficients because $H$-spaces are simple, so you can leverage whitehead's theorem+Hurewicz on the universal covers which are simply connected. This version is sometimes called the "Strong whitehead theorem."
 An even stronger version is one for simple spaces which can be proven by passing to the universal cover.